# Node.js not parsing external javascripts correctly

Tags: node.js, express, pug

So the problem is that node.js doesn't send my javascript files correctly. I can find them in the html code, but they are not executed by the browser. Those js files don't even appear in the firebug's NET panel when I reload the page.

I am using Express with Jade.

Any ideas how to fix this issue? Or what's causing it?

Comment: More information? Are you including the files in your templates? Can we see your templates. You need to have a `script(type='text/javascript' src='url')` in your template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have express.static set properly in app.configure.

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

// Also, make sure you have the most updated versions of express and node.js. Both change often.

Comment: This shows me where I have to store my custom .js files: "/public". Thanks!